# Creating Camera Sway

Tags: animation, camera, add-on

There seem to be a lot of tutorials on creating camera shake within blender but I can't find any about creating slow camera sway, as if someone is holding the camera. Is there a way to do this in blender without animating every move or is there a tutorial or addon someone can point me towards? Thanks!

Comment: You could go into the curve editor, and a random noise modifier to a curve (try x first) and scale the noise to the desired effect. First you have to add 1 keyframe for whatever property you modify (x position).

Comment: You can change the speed in the noise modifier options. You should be able to get something believable fairly easily. It is basically just a modified form of camera shake.

Comment: For a movie or a game?

Comment: @poor I'm doing it for a rendered movie

Comment: @beiller unfortunately I can't try it anytime soon but when I get the chance I will

Comment: @Chickenator Thanks. The frames are already been rendered, right? To do that in the compositor is key info here...

Comment: @poor they are not rendered so I can make changes to the camera or if there's a way I can render it and use the compositor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and easy way I found to make easy camera sways is by using the graph editor.

Steps:

1. Press `I` with the camera selected and add a rotation keyframe.
2. Open up the graph editor and select Camera `Y Euler Rotation` for example.
3. Click the `N` button to pull up the side bar
4. Click `Add Modifier` and select `Noise`
5. Now you have very fast camera shake, but you want swaying, so set the `Scale` to something like 10-20. And set the `Strength` to something like 0.2 - 0.05
6. Now you could apply this to the other rotations or even some location, but remember to randomize each noise by changing the `Phase` value for each noise modifier.

Hope that helps!